# SQL Server Full txt Search - Thesaurus Entries

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, full-text-search

I'm thinking of adding a full text search to our product (currently using SQL 2005 Enterprise), so just doing some preliminary research.

I read that you can add thesaurus entries, so "Internet Explorer" would also have related entries such as "IE", "IE7" and so on.

Would it also work in reverse, so if I enter "IE7" would it find "Internet Explorer"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should really consider upgrading to a more recent version, especially if you want to utilize some of the best parts of Full Text Search.

To your question, the short answer is **yes**.

From the [documentation for 2005](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ms345186(v=sql.90).aspx), you have two main features to customize in a thesaurus, Expansion Sets and Replacement Sets:

> An expansion set contains a group of synonyms. These synonyms are
>   identified in code by "substitution" tags ( <sub>and</sub> ). Queries
>   that contain matches in one substitution are expanded to include all
>   other substitutions in the expansion set.

and

> A replacement set contains a text pattern to be replaced by a
>   substitution set.

So if you place all three of your key words (IE, IE7, Internet Explorer) into a Substitution Set, then they will all trigger matches for each other. You can put as many substitutions in the set as you'd like - it's not a one-way definition for the substitutions.

Comment: for your info: We are looking to upgrade reasonably soon (next few months). Might postpone this until after the migration which is a pretty big job.